# C# net RSocket client invalid mime type "binary" with Java RSocket server

Tags: rsocket

I am getting an error `0000 Error {000}: [00000003] Invalid mime type "binary": does not contain '/'`

```
var client = new RSocketClient(new WebSocketTransport("ws://127.0.0.1:7000/quotes"), new RSocketOptions() { 
    InitialRequestSize = 3,
    DataMimeType = "application/x-binary",
    MetadataMimeType = "application/x-binary"
});

await client.ConnectAsync();
```

what's the mime type format to use for rsocket request stream of various binary object types? The client shows that there is a mime type.

[image]

A wireshark capture shows the error that appears to come from port 7000 the Java Server saying that the Net client has produced the wrong mime type

[image]

Comment: Can you show you show the request packet also.  It looks like you are doing the right thing, but worth confirming whether it's a bug in rsocket-net, or some other setup error.

Comment: It looks like it is sending https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-net/blob/9703fc7e442beafaad6cd255ae84d85e139a179c/RSocket.Core/RSocketProtocol.cs#L724

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is a bug in RSocket-.Net. you shell pass your `RSocketOptions` derictly into `ConnectAsync` instead of passing them into the `RSocketClient` constructor:

```cs
var client = new RSocketClient(new WebSocketTransport("ws://127.0.0.1:7000/quotes"));

await client.ConnectAsync(new RSocketOptions() { 
    InitialRequestSize = 3,
    DataMimeType = "application/x-binary",
    MetadataMimeType = "application/x-binary"
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can I push a fix to the repo?

Comment: Will do that. Sorry for the inconvenience ‍♂️

Comment: @rupweb. Sorry, missread your message. Feel free to drop a PR